# How to edit daily crontab

Tags: linux

What is the line, or lines, you would add to your crontab file to run the script /etc/cron.daily/logrotate every 3 hours on Friday, Saturday, and Sunday but only once per day at midnight on the other days of the week?
What would be the command for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
0 0 * * 1-4 /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
0 */3 * * 5-7 /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

These lines will run the /etc/cron.daily/logrotate script every day at midnight from Monday to Thursday and on Saturday. On Fridays, Saturdays, and Sundays, the script will be run every three hours using the */3 syntax.

Note that the first line uses the syntax 1-4 to specify the days of the week when the script should be run at midnight. This means Monday to Thursday (1-4).

You can check crontab guru to help you with cron questions, also.

Comment: @RomeoNinov You're right. Fixed it now =]

Comment: Hey Gabriel Ozzy! Thank you It worked. I have added this command to my assignment.

Comment: Glad to hear and happy to help